# My custom dropdown/ select menu is having border problems

Tags: html, css, select, drop-down-menu, dropdownbox

I am trying to make a custom dropdown box / select menu that allows me to have rounded options. I have it nearly done, but there is a glitch in the side of it:

[image: Strange line glitch]

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Custom Select</title>
  <style>
    .custom-select {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .select-selected {
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
      padding: 10px;
      padding-right: 9px;
      border: 1px solid gray;
      border-radius: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .select-items {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px solid gray;
      border-top: none;
      border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
      z-index: 999;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .select-items div {
      padding: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .select-items div:hover {
      background-color: lightgray;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .select-selected.active {
      border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      const customSelect = document.querySelector(".custom-select");
      const selectSelected = customSelect.querySelector(".select-selected");
      const selectItems = customSelect.querySelector(".select-items");
      const optionDivs = selectItems.querySelectorAll("div");

      selectSelected.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (selectItems.style.display === "none") {
          selectItems.style.display = "block";
          selectSelected.classList.add("active");
        } else {
          selectItems.style.display = "none";
          selectSelected.classList.remove("active");
        }
      });

      optionDivs.forEach(function(div) {
        div.addEventListener("click", function() {
          const selectedOptionText = div.textContent;
          selectSelected.textContent = selectedOptionText;
          selectItems.style.display = "none";
          selectSelected.classList.remove("active");
        });
      });

      document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (!customSelect.contains(e.target)) {
          selectItems.style.display = 'none';
          selectSelected.classList.remove("active");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="custom-select">
    <div class="select-selected">Select an option</div>
    <div class="select-items">
      <div>Option 1</div>
      <div>Option 2</div>
      <div>Option 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried several "Code fixers", which didn't work at all. Then I tried changin the padding-right values, margins, and several other style realted things. I can't figure this out. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem by changing the default value of box-sizing property to border-box like this:

```
          box-sizing: border-box;
```

or by adding it directly to your.select-items class.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was also wondering if you can figure out why, for the first time that I click on it, I have to click twice? Also, the bottom option should be the only one to have the rounded gray option on hover, but I think I can deal with that. Again, thanks!

Comment: For some reason your code first assumes that the display property is not set to "none" so it sets it "none" on the first click, then "block" on the second one. You can solve the problem by either wiriting "display:non" as an inline-css on your select-items div, or by switching the condition in your javascript to make the "if" statement checks the "block" property and the "else" for "none" property. As for the hover effect the effect is applied to all divs that fall under "select-items" class. You can solve the problem by writing a dedicated class and apply it only on that last option div.